# cocos2d-x What is the best practice to make a sprite every time I need it or just change its texture?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I need a similar asset changed on the screen with the same size, so, the best practice would be to change the texture of the sprite or make a new sprite and release the previous one? I see no difference on performance by now on my poker game I am making but I would like to know that maybe in the future implementing it on android would be a problem on performance, and so about the best practice on coding I don't see a mention of it on the documentation of cocos2d-x neither on the web. I really would like to know better what exactly goes on on both of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new Sprite each time. 
I don't really think there will be any performance issues.
You could test the performance yourself on your desired target platform/s by doing a texture swap on a bunch of Sprites (100 or 1000 sprites) and then repeat the test with the same amounts of Sprite but creating them and releasing them.